# Eclipse won't open after installing openjfx [Deepin]

Tags: java, gtk, eclipse, deepin

I was attempting to use JavaFX, and I found that I needed to install the `openjfx` package, as the regular `openJDK8` didn't come with the JavaFX files. However, since I did that Eclipse no longer opens. Instead, it crashes with the following crash log appearing: [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b5720ec35ee59f5d56f7709a99f70ed4).

Comment: Did you try enabling the core dump as per the error log?

Comment: After running `ulimit -c unlimited && /opt/eclipse/eclipse &> eclipseCrash.txt` the redirected file had the following in it: [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/faa5806ca7b51aeaaea23f70ffec221a). The core-dump associated was too big for gedit to open, and nano just gave gibberish. `ls -hl` said that the file was 809M, so I can understand why it was hard to open. Should I upload the core dump and post that as well?

Comment: Considering the size best not to for now. Am not any authority in this but it looks like it cannot find or has a malformed resource uri. If the file isnt too vast then the report logged at `/home/mdr/hs_err_pid5145.log` may help others to assist if you post a link as per your 'gist'.

Comment: That crash log has the same contents as the original crash log I posted, just with a different PID.